# How to rewrite module.exports object structure from javascript to typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am in a process of rewriting my node.js app in typescript, and I've stumbled across a bunch of index.js files, which have a following construct:

```
module.exports = {
  query: require('./query'),
  mutation: require('./mutation')
}
```

which is later imported like this:
`const { query } = require './module';`

I tried to rewrite it like this:

```
import {query} from './query'
import {mutation} from './mutation'

export default {
  query,
  mutation
}
```

but then I can't access the query object by `import {query} from './query';`

How can I successfully convert the following structure to ts, so that I don't have to import the whole module? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you need to do export {
query,
mutation,
}

default is for only one export general like object

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).